# RUNNING BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid Credentials

Tags: google-bigquery

I am uploading files to my BigQuery account by using bq.py script.
Once in a while I get the message "RUNNING BigQuery error in load operation: Invalid Credentials" with error code 1. However, checking the table, i see the data inserted properly.
In job history all is ok.
It is also happening while uploading from Google Cloud.

I am running several scripts in parallel, using bash with cronjobs.

What can be the problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did you get the answer?